# Visualforce Lookup field not allowing entry for certain profiles

Tags: visualforce, profile, security, field-level-security, pricebookentry

I have a visualforce form with 3 entry fields, 2 of which work for all profiles but one doesn't. It works for admin profile though. I've checked the VF security setting and field level security on objects but to no avail. Please help!
The lookup is using the PriceBookEntry Product as a lookup, as it has to search OrderItem products for a match.

This is what the page looks like for Admin profile:

[image]

This is what it looks like for all other profiles:
[image]

The code for the page section:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Search by Account/Product">
    <apex:inputField id="acct" label="Account" value="{!rma.AccountId}" required="false"/>
    <apex:inputField id="prod" label="Product" value="{!pbe.Product2Id}" required="false"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

The security for the VF page (users are of the CSR/IPC profiles):

[image]

These same profiles can see the field in my Dev environment, but not in my Partial environment. I've compared profiles and the Partial environment has more access than in Dev, yet the field doesn't show. The PBE access for the profiles is the same in Dev as in Partial, so is Product and OrderItem. What have I missed?

Here are the field accessibility comparisons for the SysAdmin profile and CSR profile:
[image][image][image]

Comment: Go to the product field and click on "view field accessibility" and see if it is read only for the profiles which do not see the lookup

Comment: I've double checked field accessibility on all fields on Product, Pricebook, PriceBookEntry, OrderItem for the CSR profile and compared them from Dev to Partial - all fields related to product have the same accessibility. I've also compared them for System Admin to CSR and also no different... argh!

Comment: I've edited the post to show the comparisons between the SysAdmin and CSR profiles on Partial sandbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field accessibility will show access to the fields assuming they profile has access to the object.

Ensure the profile has **edit** or **create** access to the PriceBook object and at least **read** on the product since you are coming from the object pricebookentry in your class

Here is an example for you:

1. Profile: PriceBook (Read)
2. Profile: Product (Read)

**Apex Class**

```
public class productTestController{

    public PriceBookEntry pbe {get;set;}
    public Opportunity opp {get;set;}
    public productTestController(){
        pbe = New PriceBookEntry();
        opp = New Opportunity();
    }

}
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page Controller="productTestController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opp.AccountId}" label="Account"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!pbe.Product2Id}" label="Product"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Result**

[image]

Now, Update the profile to provide **create** or **edit** (whichever you choose) access to the **Price Book** object

**Result**

[image]